# Armored Ascension

Tags: magic-the-gathering

does attaching an enchantment Aura to a colorless creature make the creature the color of the Aura?  My opponent has a card with protection from all colors and I have a Brass Squire with Armored Ascension attached to it.

Comment: The color, controller and tap status of an Aura is completely independent of the player or permanent which it enchants.

Answer (score 5):

No, your creature will still be colorless. An Aura would only change the color if specifically said so, such as [Sinister Strength](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Sinister%20Strength). This means that your opponent's creature is not protected from your Brass Squire.